# Android TextBox input animation not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This textbox animation code will occupy the space of the buttons and widen the width so that the user can have more space to type.(buttons will be hidden just like the messenger-type animation),  The code have IskeyboardOpen feature that will enable the textbox to be return on it's original size when the keyboard is minimize

my problem is why does the animation will only take effect on the second click, it will not take effect on the first click.

```
public void expandEditText(View view) {
    if (!isEditTextClicked || !isExpanded) {
        // The EditText is clicked for the first time or it is currently collapsed
        expandEditTextAnimation();
    } else {
        collapseEditText();
    }
}
private void expandEditTextAnimation() {
    if (!isEditTextClicked) {
        isEditTextClicked = true;

        // Calculate the expanded width based on the parent layout width
        int expandedWidth = ((ViewGroup) editText.getParent()).getWidth();

        // Set the expanded width to the EditText
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = editText.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = expandedWidth;
        editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        // Position the EditText over the buttons
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
        editTextParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, R.id.imageView2);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        // Hide the buttons
        locationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        captureButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        isExpanded = true;
    } else {
        // Check if the keyboard is open
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
            collapseEditText();
        } else {
            isEditTextClicked = false;

            // Calculate the original width of the EditText
            int originalWidth = editText.getWidth();

            // Set the original width to the EditText
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = editText.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = originalWidth;
            editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            // Position the EditText back to its original position
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
            editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
            editTextParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF);
            editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

            // Show the buttons
            locationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            captureButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            isExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}


private void collapseEditText() {
    // Calculate the original width of the EditText
    int originalWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.edit_text_width);

    // Set the original width to the EditText
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = editText.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = originalWidth;
    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // Show the buttons
    locationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    captureButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Position the EditText back to its original position
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams();
    editTextParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF);
    editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

    isExpanded = false;
    isEditTextClicked = false;
}
```